# 8051 microcontroller assembly language elevator coding

Tags: microcontroller, programming, assembly, 8051, intel

```
     ORG    00H

MAIN:   
    MOV P1, #00H        ; motor
    MOV P2, #00H        ; buttons P2.0-2.2, sensors P2.3-2.5

FLOOR1: 
    JNB P2.0, FLOOR2        ; check button
    SETB    P1.1            ; start motor to go down
    JNB P2.3, $         ; check sensor, cont until it reaches 1st floor
    CLR P1.1            ; stops motor
    SJMP    MAIN

FLOOR2:
    JNB P2.1, FLOOR3
    JNB P2.3, FLOOR2DOWN    ; check if lift is on floor 1
    SETB    P1.0            ; starts motor upwards
    JNB P2.4, $
    CLR P1.0    
    SJMP    MAIN

FLOOR2DOWN:
    JNB P2.1, FLOOR3
    JNB P2.5, FLOOR2        ; check if lift is on floor 3
    SETB    P1.1
    JNB P2.4, $
    CLR     P1.1
    SJMP    MAIN

FLOOR3:
    JNB P2.2, MAIN      ; check button floor 3
    SETB    P1.0            
    JNB P2.5, $         ; cont until it reaches floor 3
    CLR P1.0

    SJMP    MAIN

END
```

I am working on a very simple model elevator using 8051 microcontroller (above is my assembly coding for it). It will have:

- Ground Floor
- First Floor and,
- Second floor.

I have trouble in configuring the coding with sensors (I will use IR sensors later). Now I am using pushbutton to replace the sensor.

The thing is, when I press button on my keypad which is a "pushbutton" the motor ONLY keeps running as long as i keep holding and pressing the switch.
And I need the motor to be running until it reaches a certain floor and sensor detect it reached that floor and stops.

The elevator motor should work like, it will check all the sensors and if there is elevator car in that respective floor it will move the elevator car/cage to that position and motor will stop.

Comment: Think before you code. Sit down and work out how you'd do it if you were doing all this, manually. Imagine that there is no such thing as electronics or computers. There's just you, your eyes, your hands, and some levers and such. You are the computer and the electronics. Work out the details. I usually spend 60% or more of my time doing careful consideration and design work (throwing away some, reworking other parts) before I ever write the first line of actual code. (I do, however, write exploratory code where I don't know something about a transducer and the docs fail me.)

Comment: @jonk I tried trial and error and alot of brainstorming  to assembly coding since yesterday for hours . I am very new to this coding .Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MCS_51 "Trial and error" isn't so good. One of the harder things to get across to someone else is DON'T CODE and instead to sit down, THINK, and work through the details on paper. I mean DOWN TO THE LAST DETAIL on paper. Every single thing. When I was to write a software server application that had to serve thousands of clients and had to withstand a power-off event losing only zero or one transaction (that was my allowance), I sat down on a whiteboard and worked out all the details for weeks. The coding took me four days. It's still running. Zero bugs after 9 yrs now.

Comment: Do you need to use an 8051?  There are many, many modern MCUs that have C compilers.

Comment: I completely agree with @jonk. And here is some more advice. Stop thinking flow diagrams and start thinking state diagrams. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram

Comment: @Mattman944 Our college course uses 8051 only and assembly language only.

Comment: @jonk  i am actually lost on this project. any help regrading the coding suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: @MCS_51 I'll consider expending time tomorrow. I used to do a lot of 8051 assembly coding... 30+ years ago. I still have a box of 100 80C32 sitting here on a shelf. And if I find your writing clear enough in the question, I'll be more tempted. But for now, I'm off to sleep.

Comment: You need some variables to remember the past history. They can be memory locations, or if you only need a few, you can use registers. "floor_selected", "last_floor_sensor" might be good choices to start.

Comment: You probably don't want a new floor selection to preempt the previous selection (don't want to reverse a car between floors). So, you probably want another variable: "next_floor_selected". These are just clues, like jonk said, plan the whole thing before you code.

Comment: @MCS: Did you research state diagrams as suggested above? When you have start drawing a diagram and post it in your question. There are free tools online such as http://madebyevan.com/fsm/ (but it's probably not the best).

Comment: @MCS_51 Well, I'm just glad someone provided an answer for me. I was considering other approaches, but to be honest about it I didn't think you provided enough detail about your hardware situation (pin assignments and functions) for me to figure out how to reverse the motor. So I'm glad someone else provided some kind of answer. If you provide lots of hardware detail to your question, I might still add something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design first, code later. Plan everything out using logic, flow diagrams, state diagrams, etc. Your problems are with the logic, not the coding. Jonk has done 8051, I have not. I have done 6502 and 6800 assembly, these are similar.

At first you might be tempted to have states based on physical position.

[image]

But, an elevator really only has 3 states, going up, going down, stopped.

[image]

This is only one possible design, there are other valid designs. I have made some assumptions, if I got some wrong, you may need to scrap all this and start over.

All of your buttons and sensors are momentary, you need variables to remember the previous (last) button/sensor activated for each of these. A variable can be stored in a memory location or a register. I have used long descriptive names, in assembler you probably want shorter names.

Floor_Selected: a variable to remember what floor the user has selected. I have assumed a queue of one.

Last_Floor_Sensor: a variable to remember what floor sensor was activated last.

The third is not as obvious, but without it, the elevator will switch directions mid-floor, you probably don't want that.

Next_Floor_Selected: If the elevator is in motion, remember where to go next.

You also need a variable to represent the state of the elevator:
Elev_State: let: Stop = 0, Up = 1, Down = 2

Now, the basic flow:

```
Floor_Selected = 0
Next_Floor_Selected = 0
Last_Floor_Sensor = 0
Elev_State = Stop

Loop
{
    Read all buttons, save active button in Next_Floor_Selected variable
    If Elev_State = Stop   // Only allow the next command when stopped 
       Floor_Selected = Next_Floor_Selected 

    Read all sensors, save active sensor in Last_Floor_Sensor variable

    Update state based on diagram. Set motor direction based on state 
}
```

Notes:

The loop must be iterated fast, the buttons and sensor must be polled fast.

If multiple buttons are pressed at the same time, you will need to arbitrarily prioritize them. It doesn't really matter, the last button released will get priority.

I have guessed on some of the logic details. As it is, the next floor is in a queue, the car will travel to the next floor selected, it will not stop at in-between floors.

The preempt logic that was added to prevent reversals mid-floor has a downside, if the elevator starts at floor 0, floor 2 button is pressed, elevator starts moving toward floor 1, if button 1 is pressed before it gets to floor 1, a real elevator will stop at floor 1; With this logic, it will not.

Before you code, test the logic by stepping through it manually. Test multiple scenarios until you are sure that it does what you want. Then code.